# Mounting real rootfs after initial booting using initrd

Tags: initramfs, root-filesystem, initrd

I'm booting kernel with `root=/dev/ram0` on a embedded environment.

After initial booting, how can I mount real rootfs present at `/dev/mtd3` and make it as the only rootfs.

I'm using `root=/dev/ram0` because `root=/dev/mtd3` is not working.

Comment: Why is `root=/dev/mtd3` not working? Is `root=/dev/mtd3` not working because of missing compiled-in drivers? Need the drivers for accessing the MTD be loaded by the inirial ramfs?

Comment: Can you just mount it from within the initial ramfs (like `mount /dev/mtd3 /`)?

Comment: What bootloader are you using? u-boot? Can you access the mtd rootfs from the bootloader command line? The bootloader must be able to read it if it is the only rootfs.